# How can I sort the search results alphabetically?

Tags: search

I would like to sort the search results alphabetically in Drupal 6.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the search results of Views, Then you can expose a filter related with you are looking for, and assign the sort condition alphabetically. If you want to expose the sort condition, you can do this with views 3, and with views 2 using the hook query_alter().

Remember that you can use the operator 'Contains' if you want to be more laxed in the search.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but I would like to use the Search block of Drupal or the Advanced search not the views.Is it possible?Thanks

Comment: I think that you can expose the Views search box in a block (creating the respective display for a block). Regarding the search module, I think that Faceted Search module http://drupal.org/project/faceted_search or his related modules could be a start point.